# Minimum free disk space needed for Elasticsearch segment merges

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

What is the minimum free storage space Elasticsearch nodes/total cluster should have to ensure smooth merging of segments accounting for index optimize calls. Lucene recommends 3X index size space [1] especially during forced merges. Our use case is not memory bound. Does that mean I should plan capacity based on only 1/3 total disk space?

[1] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6386?focusedCommentId=14391162&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14391162

PS: There are no disk based circuit breaker turned on by default and the index just appears to go red when there is no free disk space. So I wanted to set safeguards at my end to avoid this issue. Elasticsearch documentation on hardware configuration pertaining to disk size is pretty sparse and hence this post.